# Extract only date from gridview

Tags: date, datetime, datagridview

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How do I extract only the date from this code?

While executing it showing this

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Comment: is your date string in the right syntax? "yyyy-MM-dd"?

Comment: Yes..................

Comment: The error indicates the string in the cell is not a valid DateTime string. How are you checking this string value?

Comment: Additionally, what value is in the cell at the time it is parsed?